# How to pass parameters to apoc.atomic.update?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

For example, I would like to perform the following query:

```
with a, b:
    call apoc.atomic.update(a, "x", "b.x")
```

However, this fails due to the internal conversion of the update string to

```
WITH $container as n with n set n.x=b.x
```

which makes `b` undefined. Is it possible to pass `b` as a parameter?

(I know that this particular update may be achieved by `with a, b set a.x = b.x`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to fetch and send the value property value, like this:

```
with a, b:
call apoc.atomic.update(a, "x", toString(apoc.map.get(properties(b), "x")))
```